# How to get effect like Dodge & Burn tool in photoshop, but nondestructively?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Does anyone know how to get effect like Dodge & Burn tool in photoshop, but nondestructively? Any normal solutions with soft light doesn't change saturation of the color, and I'm looking for effect similar for the Tool. Anyone ideas? :D

Comment: I don't know if it is possible in your situation, but you could perhaps use dodge & burn tools on a raster layer ( or a copy of another raster layer). You could then use Clipping masks or Layer masks on the "dodge & burn layer" if necessary. [Something like this, for instance](https://db.tt/zQMT8q67).

Comment: This is possible and I do this If i need it that way, but for me it doesn't sound very "nondestructively" - If I change colors of below layer I will have to do that again :( But still thank you for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use curves adjustment layers with a mask instead of dodge and burn which allows for changing the amount of "dodge" or "burn" overall and changes to the brush strokes via the mask.

A great tutorial on doing this that goes into great detail & is fairly easy to follow is PHLEARN's video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kR6yKfoR8eA

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all thank you for answer. I do know Phlearn resources quite well, what I ask for is not usual Dodge&Burn solutions that are based on Curves/Soft Light layer/Gray Layer - but something that works similar to a Photoshop tool Dodge&Burn. If you give it a try you will notice that a built in tool also increases saturation while burning, that doesn't happen in those previous methods. While usually I don't want to have that, I got a case where this brings much more nice results that I want, yet I don't want to flatter whole image just to use those tools :/